# Can't hear System Sound in simulator or on device

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, ios-simulator

I can't seem to get the AudioServices sounds to play, either on the device or in the simulator. Here is my code:

```
NSString *sndPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"click" ofType:@"aiff"];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:sndPath], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
```

I have checked my system prefs, and yes I do have "Play user interface sound effects" ticked on... What might I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm attempting to create an audio click as the user moves touches across the device, so I need it to rapidly play the same sound. Should I use AVAudioPlayer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't dispose the sound until after it finishes playing. You can do something like this:

```
AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundID, NULL, NULL, (AudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc)AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID, NULL);
```

Slightly icky, since we're assuming that it doesn't use the Pascal calling convention (i.e. AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID() can handle the extra NULL argument).

Comment: Is that going to cause problems if I am rapidly calling the sound and sometimes I want to restart it before it has finished the previous one?

Comment: I think they're created as independent objects, so they end up playing over each other. Apart from that, it should work. Try it and see.

Comment: Well it *does* work thanks!... But the performance hit is pretty nasty unfortunately. My frame rate drops from about 25fps to 16-17fps. I tried to optimise it by moving the actual sound creation code into the viewDidLoad, but now the clicks only happen intermittently (and the performance hit is still there). Should I use AVAudioPlayer instead?

Comment: If the sound creation is in viewDidLoad, I'm assuming you've moved sound disposal into viewDidUnload and dealloc. Also note that I'm not sure what the "null" system sound ID is; presumably it's 0, but this isn't documented.

Comment: oooh yes thanks - thought I had to call dispose every time, not just on the viewDidUnload... That makes it loads faster thanks! Do I need to put it in dealloc as well as viewDidUnload?

Comment: Alternatively, you can call viewDidUnload in dealloc (you might consider this icky, though). Remember to prevent a double-free ;)